# How to theoretically calculate amount of product in first-order reaction?

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics, kinetics

I was wondering if it was possible to calculate the amount of product theoretically produced from in vivo (human) values to determine if that's the only enzyme causing the increase in amount of product. The rate of the reaction is dependent on enzyme concentration, and assumes that enzyme $K_m << [product]$ (in rats at least).

From the papers I have read, others have calculated the theoretical concentration (in rats) by:

$[product] = (k_{cat}/K_m) * [substrate] * [enzyme]$

However, as far as I remember $K_m$ is dependent on multiple environmental factors and $K_{cat}$ can change as well.

Thus, I'm wondering how I could theoretically calculate it.

Post-edit:

My questions are more this:

- Can I use the $K_m$ and $K_{cat}$ I found in papers for the reaction (also found in humans), given that they differ greatly between papers.
- Is the equation given above correct for a first-order reaction?
- Any papers or books I can read to learn more about this?
- Any ideas to calculate this?

Comment: I suggest googling the issue a bit, [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8746786/) that I found quickly looks like it addresses some of your concerns directly (notably accuracy of K parameter estimates). Also it would help to link some of the resources you seem to have found.

Comment: You need to set out your problem — or an example — with actual values, and what you want to calculate. Without this I doubt whether anyone can help you.

Comment: The answer to question 2, I think, is an emphatic yes, _provided that the substrate conc is way below Km_ (the Michaelis-Menten equation then describes a first-order reaction).  Two great sources are Fersht [Structure and Mechanism in Protein Science](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Structure-Mechanism-Protein-Science-Catalysis/dp/0716732688) and  Frost and Pearson [Kinetics and Mechanism](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed038p535.1)